# How to change the text color of a div on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a `button` that changes color when you hover over it/click on it. However, I ran into an issue. There is a space between the text and the edges of the `div` section, and if you hover over the `button`, it turns black but the text does not turn white. I put `color:white;`. I am not sure as to why this does not fix the problem.

Here is my code:

```css
p {
    margin: 0px;
}


.button {

    width: 66px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px black solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;

}

.button:hover {

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

a {

    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;   
}

a:hover {

    color: white;  
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <p> <a href="https://www.google.com">  Click Me! </a> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mur9bLde/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just change your `a:hover` to `.button:hover a`
everything will look great. :>

```css
p {
        margin: 0px;
    }
    
    .button {
        width: 66px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 2px black solid;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    
    a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .button:hover a{
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<div class="button">

        <p> <a href="https://www.google.com">  Click Me! </a> </p>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so heres the deal. You made it too complex. If you had problem with the spaces, its because < a > tag is diplayed inline by default and it makes gap between it's container sometimes.

Here's your code, cleaned and working : https://jsfiddle.net/m6dphvm1/

```
<a class="button" href="https://www.google.com">  Click Me! </a>
```

---

```
a.button {
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your CSS is that your anchor(link) color is black, when you hover on the button you are changing the background of button to black, i.e both anchor color and background are black. due to that text is not being visible.

Change either background-color of button or anchor color to a differnt color and that should work. For example I'm changing the color of anchor to blue.

```
.button:hover {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    a {
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: none;   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an inline element, meaning it's designed to be nested in plain text (or what otherwise could be). It's only occupying the immediate space around the text.

However, `a` tags are also totally allowed to wrap around elements according to the HTML5 spec (not that anyone would stop you otherwise, it's just convention). So if you want the `a` tag to occupy the entire space just wrap it around the element.

Better yet, only use the `a` tag. The rest is basically redundant:

```
<a class="button" href="https://www.google.com">
    Click Me!
</a>
```

```
.button {
  width: 66px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  border: 2px black solid;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hyp4a9ya/